# Github PR triggers multiple Jenkins jobs but reports only the state of the last job

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I currently have GitHub connected to Jenkins and for every pull request, GitHub triggers a Jenkins job which seems to work fine. I am extending this to trigger multiple jobs, let's say on a new pull request, I have multiple JenkinsFiles  which are basically running different configurations.

All the jobs are triggered correctly, but the status reported back to github is overwritten. For 1 PR I will trigger:

```
Job1
Job2
Job3
```

But I get only the status of Job3:

```
continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge 
continuous-integration/jenkins/branch
```

I would like to see something like:

```
continuous-integration/jenkins/job1 
continuous-integration/jenkins/job2 
continuous-integration/jenkins/job3
```

I have already tried to set a custom commit context on the JenkinsFile of each job, but it doesnt seem to be working. Any suggestions how to solve it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`github` uses commit statuses to identify build results. In your case it is showing the latest one since the `commit context` is the same. To show results of all jobs in `github` you would have to change the commit context for each of them. This can be done via official `github status API` which can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses)

Since you are using Jenkins what you want can be achieved by using existing plugin called **GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin**. It implements `github status API` and can set a different context for each job. The plugin repository can be found [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin).

According to [this](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/142) discussion from plugin issue page and an answer by **audleman** there this is what has to be done:

> One Pull Request to Trigger Multiple Jobs
>
> In the job configuration, go to:
>
> `Build Triggers -> GitHub Pull Request Builder -> Trigger Setup...`
>
> Change `Commit Status Context` to be unique for each job.